# Double Quotes in Choice column show as &quot; in Display Form (DispFrom.aspx)

Tags: 2013, choice-field, display-form

When one of the choices for a Choice field contains a double quote, the display form (`DispForm.aspx`) will display `&amp;quot;` rather than the double quote. When creating a new item, editing an item, or displaying the field in a view, it displays correctly. This does not appear to be the case for SharePoint 2010.  I believe this is a bug introduced in SharePoint 2013.

Does anyone have a recommendation on a possible solution or workaround? Does it make sense to put some JavaScript/jQuery on the display form to try to fix how the text is displayed?

Comment: Is this on a custom form or the stock dispform?

Comment: See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/ampersand-in-a-choice-of-a-choice-field-appears-html-encoded

Answer (score -1):

Try this which has resolved the same issue for multiple lines of text.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@NIOText2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="@NIOText2" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>